# No Activity found to handle Intent (android intent)

Tags: android-intent, android-activity, xamarin, uri, start-activity

I receive error message "No activity to handle Intent" when trying to start a android.intent in my onCreate method.

```csh
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        Button button = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.myButton);

        button.Click += delegate {
            var intent = new Intent (Intent.ActionCall); 
            StartActivity (intent);
        };
    }
}
```

ActionCall = "android.intent.action.CALL".
If I use an URI the Activity starts as it expected.

```csh
button.Click += delegate {
    var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse ("tel:1112223333");
    var intent = new Intent (Intent.ActionView, uri); 
    StartActivity (intent);
};
```

How can I start a android.intent without using URI? 
The code is based on the simple Phone dialer example from Xamarin.

Comment: Are you testing this on a device? If so, this can happen if your device doesn't have an application to process phone calls (eg, a tablet).

Comment: Also, android.intent.action.VIEW is not the same as android.intent.action.CALL. A view action will trigger the package manager to find applications that can process the URI you provide. As its a `tel` URI, apps like the contacts manager can process it to store that phone number as a new contact.